# Django: reverse(view_function) does raises NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, url, django-views

Reversing by view-name works, and reversing by view-method, too.

But if the URLs use a prefix reversing by view-method does not work. At least in my case.

Old code

```
url=reverse('myapp:foo-view')
```

New code. Both versions don't work

```
url=reverse(foo_view)

url=reverse(foo_view, prefix='myapp')
```

Again, reversing by view-method works perfectly if the URLs have no prefix.

Background: Jumping to the matching source code with an IDE is fun.

Comment: Strange, I use extensively what you refer to as 'old code', why exactly isn't working?

Comment: Path on string will be deprecated, but  I have not news about import string will be removed. Why do you say that?

Comment: Where did you read that reversing like that is deprecated? Certainly using strings in a urlpattern is deprecated, but I don't recall hearing the same about reversing.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/internals/deprecation/ The ability to reverse() URLs using a dotted Python path will be removed. The example uses a named pattern. This won't be deprecated. I changed the question since the deprecation of dotted paths is not relevant in this context.

Comment: Show us your url configuration. At the very least, you're misusing the name 'prefix'. The `myapp` in `myapp:foo-view` is a namespace, and reversing a namespaced url by the view function itself is not supported.

Comment: @knbk your hint "reversing a namespaced url by the view function itself is not supported" was good. I found this issue: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17914. My question is solved now. If you want to, you can write an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reverse() does not support namespaced view references

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17914